# How to get only the one employee name from each department if the max salary is same from more than one employee

Tags: oracle, plsql, correlated-subquery

I am using below query:

```
SELECT rownum, job_id, employee_id, first_name, last_name, phone_number, salary
FROM employees OUTER
WHERE salary =
(
SELECT MAX(salary)
FROM employees
WHERE job_id = OUTER.job_id
GROUP BY job_id
)
AND ROWNUM < 6;
```

And getting below result:

```
1   AD_PRES 100 Steven  King    515.123.4567    24000
2   AD_VP   101 Neena   Kochhar 515.123.4568    17000
3   AD_VP   102 Lex De Haan 515.123.4569    17000
4   IT_PROG 103 Alexander   Hunold  590.423.4567    9000
5   FI_MGR  108 Nancy   Greenberg   515.124.4569    12008
```

[image: table]

But the problem is I want only one name for each `JOB_ID`. And that should be decided by alphabetical preference in `FIRST_NAME`.

Comment: No images thanks. Just proper CREATE and INSERT statements and/or an sqlfiddle

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use a subquery which contains the `job_id` for the first name you want to retain.  I wrapped your original query in a common table expression to make it more readable.

```
WITH t AS
(
    SELECT rownum, job_id, employee_id, first_name, last_name,
        phone_number, salary
    FROM employees OUTER
    WHERE salary =
    (
        SELECT MAX(salary)
        FROM employees
        WHERE job_id = OUTER.job_id
        GROUP BY job_id
    )
    AND ROWNUM < 6;
)

SELECT t1.rownum, t1.job_id, t1.employee_id, t1.first_name, t1.last_name,
    t1.phone_number, t1.salary
FROM t t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT job_id, MAX(first_name) AS max_name
    FROM t
    GROUP BY job_id
) t2
    ON t1.job_id = t2.job_id AND t1.first_name = t2.max_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [analytic functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174):

```
select * from (
    SELECT job_id, employee_id, first_name, last_name, phone_number, salary,
    RANK() over (
        job_id 
       order by 
           salary desc, 
           first_name, 
           employee_id -- adding employe_id breaks ties in the ordering 
       ) as rnk 
    FROM employees 
) where rnk = 1;
```

This will probably also perform better then the subselect.

All this is written without a database at hand, so it might/will contain typos

Comment: Getting this error:ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 3 Column: 9

Comment: @chanchalpanda there was a ',' missing between 'salary' and 'RANK()'

Comment: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 4 Column: 9